# Confusing type relationship

Tags: java

I saw the following recently on this site:

```
for (HashMap.Entry<Object,Object> e : new TreeMap<>().entrySet()) 
  System.out.println(e);
```

To my surprise, this compiles and runs fine. I have also tried adding entries to the map so there is actually something to downcast and fail doing so, this worked fine as well. How can a `TreeMap` entry be cast to `HashMap.Entry`? These two aren't even on the same branch of the hierarchy.

### Update

Although this matter is resolved now, I include the following just for fascination—the following *does not* compile:

```
for (TreeMap.Entry<Object,Object> e : new HashMap<>().entrySet())
  System.out.println(e);
```

It happens that `TreeMap` defines `TreeMap.Entry`, which hides `Map.Entry`.

Comment: I think it's Map.Entry: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html

Comment: You might run into problems if your `TreeMap` actually had entries... `ClassCastException` specifically.

Comment: @Powerlord I have updated the question; I have actually tried that out, but posted the original snippet as found on this site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although you are accessing it on `HashMap`, `Entry` is actually a (implicitly `static`) member type declared in `Map`. `TreeMap#entrySet` has a return type of `Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>`. This is the same `Entry` type.

Comment: Hmmm... after checking, this is obviously right, but such a language rule *does* seem to invite confusion. What is the benefit of `HashMap` inheriting the type `Entry` from its interface?

Comment: @WilliamF.Jameson I'm not sure. If you've already imported the type `HashMap`, you wouldn't need to import the type `Map`. (Though that doesn't seem to be enough of a reason.)

Comment: No, that reason is too weak to cover for the nuisances :) (BTW you mean `Entry` instead of `Map`).

Comment: @WilliamF.Jameson Sorry, I was away for a second there. Which `Entry` vs `Map` are you referring to? Above, I'm saying if you have `import java.util.HashMap`, you can use `HashMap.Entry` instead of `Map.Entry`, which would require another `import java.util.Map`.

Answer (score 1):

`new TreeMap<>().entrySet() returns Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>` and you are iterating over every entry of the set `(Entry<Object, Object>)`. Hence it compiles. In java 8 you can replace the for loop like

```
new TreeMap<>().entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I am iterating over the static type of `HashMap.Entry`, not just `Entry`, I don't see what you mean here.